# Variable changing value, ruby

Tags: ruby

I am not sure how this variable called origString is changing value in my loop

```
def scramble_string(string, positions)
  i = 0
  origString = string
  puts origString
  newString = string
  while i < string.length
    newString[i] = origString[positions[i]]
    i = i + 1
  end
  puts origString
  return newString
end
```

for example if I run scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0])
origString changes from "abcd" in the first "puts" to "dbcd" in the second one.
How am I changing the value of origString if I am only declaring it once?

Comment: Ruby strongly recommends using names like `orig_string`, no upper-case letters, as case has significant meaning in Ruby.

Comment: The variable isn't changing its value. The value is changing its content, because you tell it to on line 7.

Comment: @JörgWMittag can you elaborate? how it works " value is changing its content".

Comment: @Dharshan: If an object supports changing its state, you can change its state by sending it a message telling it to change its state. For example, you can change the state of a string by sending it the `[]=` message or the `upcase!` message.

Comment: @JörgWMittag based on tadman's answer when we say `x = y` both object_ids are same, If we change entire value of `x = 'pest'`, object_ids will change completely. If we check before changing value object_ids of `x[0]` and `y[0]` are different. . But changing a single value in `x`  (i,e `x[0]`) reflects in original string `y`, HOW?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `x = y` in Ruby that creates a variable with a reference to exactly the same object. Any modifications to `x` will apply to `y` and vice-versa:

```
y = "test"
x = y

x[0] = "b"

x
# => "best"
y
# => "best"
```

You can tell because of this:

```
x.object_id == y.object_id
# => true
```

They're identical objects. What you want is to make a copy first:

```
x = y.dup
x[0] = "b"
x
# => "best"
y
# => "test"
```

This results in two independent objects:

```
x.object_id == y.object_id
# => false
```

So in your case what you need is to change it like:

```
orig_string = string.dup
```

Now that being said, often the best way to process things in Ruby is by using functions that return copies, not manipulating things in place. A better solution is this:

```
def scramble_string(string, positions)
  (0...string.length).map do |p|
    string[positions[p]]
  end.join
end

scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0])
"dbca"
```

Note that's a lot more succinct than the version with string manipulation.

Comment: Or `string.chars.values_at(*positions).join`

Comment: @tadman need some explanation on your statements. when we say `x = y` both object_ids are same, but object_ids of  x[0] and y[0] are different. If we change entire value of `x = 'pest'` object_id will completely change. But changing a single value in `x` reflects in original string `y`, HOW? 
Need to know little bit more about this.

Comment: `x[0]` returns a single-character substring. Since every substring operation can produce *new, unique string*, even `x[0].object_id == x[0].object_id` is generally not true. There's only a few things that are object_id equivalent by design: Symbols, nil, true, false, and *some* numbers.